# Why do the Police work against the Rosen company?

Tags: do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

I'm still at the beginning of the book *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?*, where Deckard is sent to the Rosen family, so please try not to spoiler; I just had this question: Why does the Police/Deckard work against the Rosen company (or: why is their relationship so hostile) when both of them basically work for the state?

The state clearly pushes for colonization of the other planets and basically wants all humans to leave Earth and has ties to the Rosen company because of this.

At the same time the state works against the Rosen company through the police and hence against colonization.

I understand that the state might want some compromise: It needs the Rosen company for androids and therefore for colonization, but doesn't want the androids to be too well developed. But the relation between the police and the Rosen company still seems very hostile, in my opinion.

Comment: "Why does the police" is ungrammatical; if you're not going to accept my edit, please fix it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem for the Police is Law Enforcement. The law is that no replicants are allowed on Earth, and currently the Police have the Voigt-Kampff test to determine whether or not a suspect is indeed a replicant.

The Rosen company on the other hand, prides itself on creating better and better replicants that become more human-like with each generation. They emulate human behaviour more closely with each upgrade, and are at a point (or just tipping over the point) where the VK-test can no longer discriminate 100% between replicants and (the lowest-scoring percentile of) humans.

In effect tension is created between the interest of keeping the law and the interest of copying human behaviour better.